# "on this matter" or " in this regard" here?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, style, hyphens

In addition to the main question, it is master or master's more appropriated here?

.On the other hand, graduated with a **master’s** that provides the latest strategies to tackle agricultural-associated issues, she can demonstrate the international academic background required to take strategic decisions **on this matter**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"On this matter" is correct.

"On this matter" means "about this subject" and is very fitting here.

"In this regard" is used as reference to something previously mentioned. It would refer back to something said before the sentence in your question. Do you have the sentence that came before this one?

"master's" is correct. "master's" is short for "master's degree". The degree belongs to the master so you use the possessive 's here. "She graduated with a master's (degree) (in Chemistry)

If you are referring to a specific degree then you don't use the 's and it must be capitalised. For example, "She graduated with a Master of Sciences" (Master of Sciences is usually abbreviated to MSc).

Comment: I plan to use "on this matter" or "In this regard" to refer to  *agricultural-associated issues*

Comment: In that case, use "on this matter". You have mentioned the subject and want to say that she can makes decisions about the subject so "on this matter" is the appropriate choice.